# How to Create a long listing of all the files in this directory to a file called etcFiles.txt (In Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, permissions

I started to learn Linux. But I dont know how to solve this problem. I want to Create a long listing of all the files in /etc/ directory to a file called etcFiles.txt.When i try to run this terminal says "Permission denied".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x75vR.png)

Answer (score 0):

To long list a file in Linux, you need to use the command

```
ls -l
```

It displays the contents on the console. To store it in the file you need to redirect it using redirection operation `>` to a file like

`ls -l directoryPath > outputFile.txt`.

Here, to store the result of long listing /etc/ to file you need to use

```
ls -l /etc/ > etcFiles.txt
```

In the image linked, to store the contents of the current directory to a file you need to provide the current directory as the argument to `ls` command. In Unix/ Linux, the current directory is represented by `.`, so as shown in the screenshot, you are already in `/etc/` directory, to store long listing contents of current directory i.e. `/etc/` to the file, you need to use

`ls -l . > ~/etcFiles.txt`

However `ls` command takes the current directory as default argument `.` above can be avoided and the following command will also work

`ls -l > ~/etcFiles.txt`

Linux /Unix by default does not give any user permission to write/ create files in `/etc/` directory and requires elevated permission to make any changes in this directory. Since you do not have permission to create a new file in /etc/ directory, either you need to redirect the output to the file in some directory where you have permission like above, we are storing it in the home directory `~` or else you will have to use `sudo` for superuser permission to create new file in `/etc/` itself.

Since we need redirection operator to write file in `/etc/`, we can't simply run

<s>`sudo ls -l > etcFiles.txt`</s>

because `ls` will run with superuser permission and redirection will be done with default user permission. So you need to club in both to run in elevated permission.

To achieve that spawn a new shell with elevated permission using `sudo sh` and pass the command as a string with `-c` option as shown below

**Solution 1**

`sudo sh -c 'ls -l . >  etcFiles.txt'`

**Solution 2**

You can make use of pipe `|` by piping the output of `ls -l` to a command called `tee` which basically reads the standard input and writes it to both the standard output and one or more files. 
Since you need to write to a file inside /etc/ directory, you need to run tee with `sudo` for elevated permission.

`ls -l | sudo tee etcFiles.txt`

This will also print the output to the console. To avoid output to the console, redirect output to `/dev/null` (take it as dustbin sink to throw unwanted outputs) and your final command becomes

`ls -l | sudo tee etcFiles.txt > /dev/null`